# php sucess message didnot work after send mail

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

in contact.php i write a form to get the details, and will submit to contactprocess.php . after mail that i want to show a successs message and redirect to contact.php. in this code mail was successfully sented but alert and redirect not work.

contact.php

```
<form class="form-contact contact_form" action="contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-12">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Subject">
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="9" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Message'" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control valid" name="name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" placeholder="name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control valid" name="email" id="email" type="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" placeholder="Email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="button button-contactForm boxed-btn">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

contact_process.php

```
<?php
    $to = "nomela2170@aieen.com";
    $from = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $csubject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $cmessage = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $headers = "From: $from";
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $subject = "You have a message.";

    $logo = 'img/logo.png';
    $link = '#';

    $body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Express Mail</title></head><body>";
    $body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
    $body .= "<thead style='text-align: center;'><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>";
    $body .= "</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Name:</strong> {$name}</td>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td>";
    $body .= "</tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Subject:</strong> {$csubject}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='border:none;'><strong>Message:</strong>{$cmessage}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "</tbody></table>";
    $body .= "</body></html>";



       if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
      {
      echo "<script>alert('successfully sent.'); window.location.href='contact.php';</script>";
      }

?>
```

Comment: Your alert was created very well. Can you try to debug using visual studio code  so that you get what the mail return

Comment: @ Roko C. Buljan i nedd tp show the alert message.

Comment: @ ILIAS M. DOLAPO , yes mail was succesfully sented, but there was no alert message.

Comment: try ```die(var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)))``` to see what is inside ```mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)```

Comment: @Babak , not working bro.

Comment: what? die doesn't  work?

Comment: @Babak , not work.

Comment: then what happened? please send me what you tried and output

Comment: @Babak die(var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)))
      {
      echo "<script>alert('You are logged out'); window.location.href='new.php';</script>";
      }

Comment: where is the if statement and what is the error

Answer (score 1):

Try to leaving PHP tags for this:

```
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("successfully sent");
    window.location.href = "contact.php";
    </script>
    <?php
```